# ubuntu 20.04 - mouse right button not working in gnome

Tags: gnome, usb, mouse, button

I've just installed 20.04 on a brand new system plus a bunch of applications(gimp, blender, inkscape, cinelerra, emacs etc). From the start the right button menu has not been working, in fact the right button appears dead. Left and middle appear to function normally, and no other apparent issues with the system. At first I thought it might be a firefox issue, but the problem is the same in Nautilus.

I've done some searching and can't find a thread that describes the same problem, there's been issues with touchpads but I'm using USB mouse that previously worked without issue attached to a laptop running 16.04.

```
$ uname -a
Linux spotknife 5.4.0-28-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 17:40:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ dmesg |grep -i mouse
[    2.416881] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    3.460312] usb 1-4: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    3.620676] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0003/input/input5
[    3.620740] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:01:00.0-4/input0
[51447.130575] usb 5-1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[51447.159949] input: Logitech USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.1/0000:07:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:046D:C05A.0004/input/input14
[51447.160155] hid-generic 0003:046D:C05A.0004: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:07:00.3-1/input0
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad.

I thought I had tested with another mouse, but I must have just thought I had. The old logitech mouse is dead, right button functioing normally with a new device I got.

Please delete this thread,